# WordPress custom SQL

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have this function which contains some custom SQL:

```
    function user_comment_count_by_meta( $user_id, $meta_key )
    {
        global $wpdb;

        $count = 0;

        $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM $wpdb->comments comments INNER JOIN $wpdb->commentmeta meta ON comments.comment_ID = meta.comment_id WHERE comments.user_id = %d AND meta.meta_key = %s";

        $count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $user_id, $meta_key ) );

        return $count;
    }
```

What it should be doing is counting all the comments for a user that have a particular meta value attached to them and returning that number. So for example if a user has made 20 comments and then 11 of those have the meta value 'accepted' attached to them then the number returned would be 11.

I call the function like so:

```
<?php $count = user_comment_count_by_meta( get_the_author_meta('id'), 'accepted' ); ?>
```

However it doesn't return anything. Not sure where I have gone wrong? If any SQL geniuses could help or if anyone can spot a problem it'd be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some output, like debug instructions that displays the query etc.?

Comment: @bluish I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I mean, e.g. can you print in the log the generated query, to see if it's ok?

Comment: I don't know it in PHP, but in Java you have `System.out.println("loret ipsum")` and in JavaScript `alert("loret ipsum")`, for example

Answer (score 0):

Well,I think that the SQL it's ok, but when you call your function you are using

```
get_the_author_meta('id')
```

and this function I think that have other meaning.

If you want the ID from the post author you must use:

```
get_the_author_ID()
```

I'm not sure. really.

Comment: Tried that as well. I think it must be the SQL that's incorrect.